# Converting textbox value to hexadecimal? Javascript

Tags: javascript

JS:

```
function toHex() {
    var dec = document.getElementById('number').value;
    var hex = dec.toString(16);
    document.getElementById('number').value = hex;
}
```

HTML:

```
    <input type="text" id="number" placeholder="decimal" onkeypress="return isNumber(event)"> <br>
    <input type="button" id="toHex" onclick="toHex()" value="To Hex">
```

I'm trying to make the button convert the number in the textbox to hexadecimal (16 base), but it isn't working. It works if I use just a number as the `dec`variable, so it must be something with the `getElementById`. 
Any help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert your string to integer first.
`var dec = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);`

Answer (score 1):

`dec` is a string. Try `(+dec).toString(16)`

Answer (score 1):

Like this,

```
var dec = parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value);
```

The `parseInt()` function parses a string and returns an integer.

The radix parameter is used to specify which numeral system to be used, for example, a radix of 16 (hexadecimal) indicates that the number in the string should be parsed from a hexadecimal number to a decimal number.

Answer (score 0):

[Just take a look at this...may help you for your question](https://www.hscripts.com/scripts/JavaScript/base-converter.php)

Answer (score 0):

```
_number =  parseInt(document.getElementById('number').value)
```

You can convert the number in your text box to hex by fist Converting it to a hexadecimal string with:

```
 hexa_str = _number.toString(16);
```

and reverse the process with:

```
_number = parseInt(hexa_str , 16);
```